# Operator equivalent to 'includes'

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to JOIN a bunch of tables and I'm new to Postgres and Knex.

Is there an equivalent to the javascript operator 'includes'? e.g. I want to do something like this:

```
JOIN tbl ON somearrayofIds 'includes' tbl.id
```

Here's my fetch query:

```
db('posts AS p')
    .select(
      'p.id as postId',
      'p.user_id as pUserId',
      'p.content',
      'p.created_at',
      'p.updated_at',
      'p.image_url as postImage',
      'pr.post_id as prPostId',
      'pr.reaction_ids as prReactionIds',
      'pr.user_ids as prUserIds',
      'r.id as rId',
      'r.keyword as rKeyword',
    )
    .leftJoin('post_reactions AS pr', 'pr.post_id', '=', 'p.id')
    .leftJoin('reactions AS r', 'r.id', 'includes', 'pr.reaction_ids') // r.id is string, pr.reaction_ids is array
```

Comment: Take a look at [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
create table array_test(id int, array_fld int[]);
insert into array_test values (1, '{1, 3, 5}');

select * from array_test where 1 = ANY(array_fld);
 id | array_fld 
----+-----------
  1 | {1,3,5}

select * from array_test where 2 = ANY(array_fld);
 id | array_fld 
----+-----------
(0 rows)
```